# MPAndroidchart - Support for BigDecimal in graphs

Tags: mpandroidchart

I was searching through documentation but didn't find support for `BigDecimal`. I'm using `PieChart` in my app and need to show large values.

Please guide me if support has been provided already. If no, are there any future plans?